# How to change image map coordinates in html with respect to it's dimensions after posting through mail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html

I have one image and it is posted through iphone to gmail. I have applied image map on this image so that, on particular area user can click and forwarded to the required page. Image is working great in desktop but when checked in iphone, image dimensions are changed according to the iphone and the coordinates are disturbed. How to change image area coordinates according to the device. Is there any process? pls help.

```
//html

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
</head>

<body>
<img src="../20140111100013_640.jpg" width="640" height="640" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map"><area shape="rect" coords="104,550,144,587" href="#" id="twitter"/>

  <area shape="rect" coords="487,560,596,595" href="#" id="smallimage"/>
  <area shape="rect" coords="234,478,405,542" href="#" id="getios"/>
  <area shape="rect" coords="42,550,82,587" href="#" id="facebook"/>
<area shape="rect" coords="229,18,414,76" href="#" id="heading"/>
<area shape="rect" coords="234,402,407,469" href="#" id="checkbtn"/>
<area shape="circle" coords="320,187,86" href="#" id="circle"/>

</map>
</body>
</html>
```